# How to fix PLS-00103 error in case statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I"m using oracle sql developer and I'm trying to test case statements, but I keep getting errors ORA-06550 and PLS-00103.

```
set v_naujas_rizikos_lygis := 100;
begin
declare v_naujas_rizikos_lygis INT;
set v_naujas_rizikos_lygis :=225;

begin

    case
    when v_mokejimu_suma>0 and v_mokejimu_suma<100 then 1
    when v_mokejimu_suma>100 and v_mokejimu_suma<200 then 2
    when v_mokejimu_suma>200 and v_mokejimu_suma<300 then 3
    end v_naujas_rizikos_lygis
print(v_naujas_rizikos_lygis);
```

I need my case statment to set a new value for my variable v_naujas_rizikos_lygis. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a quick look at the manual of [this tutorial](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-case/)

Comment: `then set v_naujas_rizikos_lygis :=1` etc. (Looks like you have mixed up case _expression_ and case _statement_ syntax.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think you mean

```
v_naujas_rizikos_lygis := case
    when v_mokejimu_suma>0 and v_mokejimu_suma<100 then 1
    when v_mokejimu_suma>100 and v_mokejimu_suma<200 then 2
    when v_mokejimu_suma>200 and v_mokejimu_suma<300 then 3
    else ...
end;
```

(replace ... with a default value)

Comment: Using your case no longer gives me errors inside case statment but I'm unable to print out the value I have set for "v_naujas_rizikos_lygis". I get this error "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following." After end; statement I try to print out the value using  print(v_naujas_riziko_lygis); The error occurs in the line where print statement is declared.

Comment: Your initial code is missing 'end;' at the end. Also to print to the console, 'DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE' is usually used.